# How to inherit Odoo's POS buttons

Tags: javascript, customization, pos, odoo-13

I'm trying to add some functions in the POS buttons, specifically the button that shows up like "Validate". To test if the guide in this link https://odoo-development.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/pos/gui.html works, I'm just adding a console.log like the following:

```js
odoo.define('my_module.js_file', function (require) {
    "use strict";

    var screens = require('point_of_sale.screens');

    screens.PaymentScreenWidget.include({
    init: function(parent, options) {
        this._super(parent, options);
        //My console log message
        console.log('Hello world!')
        this.pos.on('updateDebtHistory', function(partner_ids){
            this.update_debt_history(partner_ids);
      }, this);
    },
  });
```

But the message only shows up once when the POS ends loading the data and not when I push the button. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add your code to the `Validate` button you will need to modify the payment screen widget via the `include` method (*You already did that*).

If you inspect the button from the browser you will find that it has a class `next` which is used to bind an event handler to the [click](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/addons/point_of_sale/static/src/js/screens.js#L2199) JavaScript event.

***Example*:**

```
var screens = require('point_of_sale.screens');
var PaymentScreenWidget = screens.PaymentScreenWidget;

PaymentScreenWidget.include({

    validate_order: function(force_validation) {
        console.log('Hello world!');
        this._super(force_validation);
    },

});
```